# Simultaneously connecting USB mouse and VGA monitor?

Tags: usb-on-the-go, chromecast, external-display, mouse

Is it possible to simultaneously connect a USB mouse and VGA monitor to an Android tablet?

Because of my physical disability, I would like to operate an Android tablet using a standard USB mouse, rather than the usual touch input. At the same time, I would like to mirror the tablet's display onto a standard VGA monitor.  Is this possible on an Android tablet?

From reading a [HowToGeek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/164783/how-to-connect-mice-keyboards-and-gamepads-to-an-android-phone-or-tablet/), it seems that mouse input is possible if I use an adaptor from standard USB to USB OTG.  If I insert a USB hub between the adaptor and mouse, can I also connect a VGA monitor to the tablet using a VGA to USB adaptor?

I've also heard of Chromecast.  Is this needed to mirror the tablet's display onto a VGA monitor?

Comment: It is possible to mirror the display to an equipped HDMI TV using a Google Chromecast, although you may not like the experience, I have only used it on a phone and it's usable but hardly efficient. As far as controlling the mouse, a Bluetooth mouse would probably be much easier.

Comment: @acejavelin Thanks for the tip about a Bluetooth mouse, but it would have to be a USB mouse.  My physical disability means that the mouse shape is crucial, and the mouse that works best for me is USB.

Comment: Gotcha... You can go from a USB OTG adapter to a powered USB hub and connect multiple peripherals, although whether or not a VGA display adapter would be supported would depend entirely on your tablet. However, using a USB mouse connected to the USB OTG connector or hub, and a Chromecast (which is uses WiFi) may work. If your tablet support MHL output (HDMI over USB port) to my knowledge it cannot be used in conjunction with USB OTG, it is one or the other.

Comment: BTW, I have no experience doing this, but I found this article about using a USB Mini Docking station with a tablet... it might prove useful. https://www.cnx-software.com/2015/08/29/connect-an-android-smartphone-or-tablet-to-a-monitor-usb-keyboard-and-mouse-easily-with-a-displaylink-docking-station/