# How to "tell" Android to output/mirror its display?

Tags: external-display

With inspiration from [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186863/simultaneously-connecting-usb-mouse-and-vga-monitor), I purchased this docking station to be used with my new tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab A (2017), running Android 7.1.1):

[StarTech HDMI and DVI/VGA Dual-Monitor Docking Station for Laptops - USB 3.0
(USB3SDOCKHDV)](https://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/Laptop-docking-stations/Universal-Laptop-Docking-Station-Dual-Monitor~USB3SDOCKHDV)

Top:

[image: overview]

Rear:
[image: rear inputs]

Side:
[image: side inputs]

The docking station has multiple inputs (DVI, HDMI, VGA, USB 3.0), and I am able to connect the docking station to the Samsung tablet via a USB 3.0 to USB C adapter.  The docking station does not explicitly support Android, but I thought I would give it a try.

I know that the docking station is working -- to some extent, at least -- because if I connect a USB mouse to one of the USB 3.0 ports, I am able to access Android with the mouse.

However, when I connect a VGA monitor to the docking station, nothing appears on the monitor.  Likewise, when I connect an HDMI monitor to the docking station, nothing appears on the monitor.

**Is there any way to "tell" the Android OS to output its screen** to the docking station, via the USB C output on the tablet?  In other words, before I return the docking station to the retailer, I want to make sure that there is nothing else I can try.

When I go to **Settings > Display**, I don't see any option "Export screen to external display via USB C output" or something like that.  Is there any such option?

[image: display]

Comment: To output video via USB the device itself has to support MHL, which most devices don't.

Comment: @AndyYan Thanks. How can I tell if my device supports MHL?

Comment: Just look the device up - I don't think there's a reliable app for checking on-device.